# Should I delete my old (and now irrelevant) questions which have low view counts?

Tags: discussion, clean-up, old-questions

I'm "cleaning up" my last questions with my own solutions. I found this question of mine ([Manipulating the browser chrome in a web extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49709731/manipulating-the-browser-chrome-in-a-web-extension)) while writing this question had 28 views in 369 days. I'm not even interested in the solution now.

Should I delete it?

I have also a second question ([Optimize load of file processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51319600/optimize-load-of-file-processing)) which had in 9 months just 136 views. Again, I'm not interested in the solution any more.

Delete or keep?

Comment: If you are not interested in the solution then you should leave it as it is, if you have the solution already, you can post it as an answer in that question. Who knows that someone encounters the exact same problem and posts a comment asking for a solution in the future?

Comment: @gnat I think it is (strongly) related, but not a dupe.

Answer (score 6):

> Should I delete it?

If you think there won't be any value in hope of possible answers, you may delete these questions.

If you solved them meanwhile yourself, and believe there's still value for future research, you might consider to leave a self answer instead of deletion.

Answer (score -4):

No, don't delete them. It is *content*. Do they harm anything? No.

Do they help the SE? No, a deleted queston has actually more records (posthistory, delete vote) than a yet existing one.

Once they were enough important for you to risk a downvoted, undeletable question on your profile by asking them. Are you sure that you are really not interested on the answer? And if yes, how can you be sure that also others will think the same?

What is someone comes, for example a webapi guru, and looks for all the unanswered questions about his most loved topic? You should not get away the joy (and the rep) of answering it.

(Good quality) questions are not a task to do here, not a problem here, they are an important resource. Your question is clearly a high quality one. Don't destroy resources.

On the SE, there is no limit, when can be a question answered. Most questions get an answer in some days, but it is not guaranteed. It is not like a project which was not done, it is like a long-standing research topic. Well, the research is clearly not very hot about it, but you can't be ever sure.